How to disable Live Activity on Apple Watch while keeping it enabled on iPhone?
I'm using Live Activity features in my app, but I want to customize the user experience across different Apple devices. Specifically, I'd like to:
Keep Live Activity enabled and functioning on the iPhone
Disable or prevent Live Activity from appearing on the connected Apple Watch
Is this level of device-specific control possible with Live Activity? If so, what's the best approach to implement this functionality?
What I've tried:
I've looked through Apple's documentation on Live Activity, but couldn't find specific information about device-level control.
I've experimented with ActivityKit, but haven't found a clear way to distinguish between iPhone and Apple Watch when pushing updates.
